# VimLeave event not triggered?

Tags: autocmd

~/.vimrc:

```
autocmd VimLeave * :!touch /home/odiszapc/vimleave<cr>
```

After exiting by typing `:q<CR>` the file is not created. What I'm doing wrong?

Version of ViM:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 20 2015 10:38:14)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-801, 803-808, 810-827
```

Answer (score 8):

What I was doing wrong is adding `<cr>` at the end of the line. That's work pretty well:

```
autocmd VimLeave * :!touch /home/odiszapc/vimleave
```

Comment: Yeah, you only need `<Cr>` in key mappings (`nnoremap` and friends). For autocmds, it's just a list of "normal" Vim commands. This can be a bit confusing, but does make sense: with a mapping, you want to replicate  keys a user might type; leaving of `<Cr>` for example can be quite useful. With autocmds, you just want to run some VimScript, not emulate what a user might type (although you could, with `:normal`).